# Encryption and Decryption in Text Files Java

Tags: java, encryption

I am working on a game and I have implemented save files successfully using an array of integers and adding things back to my game through those integers. Now I want to encrypt it so a player can't just go inside the text file and change the integers to go anywhere in the game. Ive figured it out somewhat I think except the ivBytes initialization and what to initialize it as:
Code: package Managers;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.ShortBufferException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import Data.SaveData;
import GameStates.LevelSelector;
import Inventory.Inventory;

public class ResourceManager {

    private byte[] keyBytes;
    private byte[] ivBytes;
    private byte[] input;
    private SecretKeySpec key;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    private Cipher cipher;

    public ResourceManager() {
        String keypass = "DAA5885FD1118E34FB7DC4F58500392DBD30D00E63B2DCF120A7A97300D0E44B";
        keyBytes = keypass.getBytes();
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length, "DES");
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void saveFile(SaveData data) {
        String saveData = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getSaveData().length; i++) {
            saveData += "" + data.getSaveData()[i] + " ";
        }
        input = saveData.getBytes();
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
        try {
            int enc_len = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, encrypted, 0);
            enc_len += cipher.doFinal(encrypted, enc_len);
        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String encryptedData = new String(encrypted);
        try (BufferedWriter saveCreator = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("./saveData/" + data.getFileName() + ".txt")))){
            saveCreator.write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length());
            saveCreator.flush();
            saveCreator.close();
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        }
    }

    public void loadFile(String fileName) {
        try (BufferedReader saveReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./saveData/" + fileName + ".txt")))){
            String data = saveReader.readLine();
            saveReader.close();
            try {
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] encrypted = data.getBytes();
            int enc_len = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, encrypted, 0);
            byte[] decrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(enc_len)];
            int dec_len = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, enc_len, decrypted, 0);
            dec_len += cipher.doFinal(decrypted, dec_len);
            String newdata = new String(decrypted);
            String tokens[] = newdata.split("\\s+");
            int[] realdata = new int[tokens.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                realdata[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            }
            Main.Main.currentWorld = realdata[0];
            Main.Main.currentLevel = realdata[1];
            Main.Main.unlockedWorld = realdata[2];
            Main.Main.unlockedLevel = realdata[3];
            LevelUtility.LevelMap.player.setLives(realdata[4]);
            LevelUtility.LevelMap.player.setInventory(new Inventory(320, 240));
            for (int i = 5; i < realdata.length; i = i + 2) {
                if (i != realdata.length - 1) {
                    LevelUtility.LevelMap.player.getInventory().addItem(realdata[i], realdata[i+1]);
                }
            }
            Main.Main.gsm.addState(new LevelSelector());
            Main.Main.gsm.setState("LevelSelectorWorld1");
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My current error is a Null Pointer Exception when declaring the IVParameterSpec since ivBytes is not initialized and I have no idea what to initialize it as. Thanks for the help.

Full Error:

> ```
> Exception in thread "handledThread: 1" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec.<init>(IvParameterSpec.java:53)
>   at Managers.ResourceManager.<init>(ResourceManager.java:38)
>   at GameStates.PauseScreen.selectOption(PauseScreen.java:85)
>   at GameStates.PauseScreen.tick(PauseScreen.java:72)
>   at Managers.GameStateManager.tick(GameStateManager.java:39)
>   at Main.Main.tick(Main.java:127)
>   at Main.Main.run(Main.java:89)
>   at Utility.handledThread.run(handledThread.java:26)
> ```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace please?

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are correct and helpful.

See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IV can be initialized to any byte array of block size, 8-bytes for DES. But for security the IV should be random bytes and different for each encryption. The IV can be prepended to the encrypted data, it does not need to be secret.

DES has an 8-byte key (only 56-bits are used) so there is no point in providing a longer key.

But, don't use DES, it is not secure, use AES, it is no more difficult to use and is secure.

AES is used exactly the same as DES with the following differences: block size and IV are 16-bytes, there are three key sizes, 128, 192 or 256 bits.

Comment: Can you show an example of using AES and the path for the getinstance on  the Cipher. Sorry, I am somewhat new to encrypting. Can the key be any byte size? Also how do I create random keys and ivs for every single save and make a decryptor for that if that is possible? Thank you!

Comment: A random IV is created using a system [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) generally available for all systems/languages. As in the answer, just concatenate the IV with the encrypted data and it is available for decrypting.